# Flutter Fastlane Jenkins xcode_backend.sh permission error

Tags: flutter, jenkins, cicd, fastlane

I have a flutter mobile app and i am using fastlane for upload ipa to testflight. We are trying to integrate to jenkins to trigger fastlane. So when i run **fastlane uploadTestFlight** i am getting error like this;

```
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fckggdkaoahppkegwycjqubefoot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

When i open the script i see

```bash
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
```

this code. When i run it manually i am getting this error

```
error: Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/.dart_tool' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)".
A crash report has been written to /var/folders/sv/mw43s0vd4l7b_yng7m24jvpr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.vIlD0J/flutter_01.log
Failed to package /...
```

FastFile codes are;

```rb
platform :ios do

  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :uploadTestFlight do
    update_info_plist(
      plist_path: "Runner/Info.plist",
      xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj",
      app_identifier: bundleId
    )
    cert
    build_ios_app(workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace", scheme: "Runner",
     export_method: "app-store",
     export_options: { provisioningProfiles: { bundleId => bundleId+" AppStore" } }
    )
    upload_to_testflight(app_identifier: bundleId)
  end

end
```

The interesting thing is when i run fastlane uploadTestFlight command on terminal without jenkins everything's work fine.